# jquery html toggle with fade?

Tags: jquery

how do I make a html toggle with fade?

```
$("#container").fadeOut(function () {         
  $("#container").html(($("#container")
    .html() === 'before') ? 'after' : 'before').fadeIn();
});
```

I've tried the code above and different code from other questions but they seem to get stuck?

Comment: Can you describe in plain text exactly what your desired outcome is?

Comment: [Works fine for me](https://jsfiddle.net/b1kgywmv/) - what are you *expecting*?  What doesn't work?  What does work?  Needs a *lot* more info.  Note that `.html() == "text"` will rely on there being no whitespace - so maybe you just need `.text().trim() == "before"` ?  Need your HTML to determine the exact issue.   What do you mean by *gets stuck*?

Answer (score 1):

```
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<head>
```

first you have to make sure you are using script tags and using jquery library,To check you have to open the console in your browser, if there is an error it will display this